# Use code pasted in Chrome developer console to Auto Enter information in joomla form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, joomla

I'm updating a bunch of Joomla sites and need to enter the same information through the admin console in each site. There are 25 individual fields in a specific module that need to be updated in each site. What I need is some type of code that I can paste into the developer console in Chrome that will fill in the 25 fields, each field holding different information.

Right now I copy and past text from a document into each of the 25 fields in the form. Very time consuming.

Not sure what type of code is easiest. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If all the field names are the same, just turn on autocomplete

Comment: Are the 25 fields variable each time or stay the same? What I mean is; do you need code to read from a file of variables to set the values?

Comment: @sinisterfrog Doesn't autocomplete require you to tab to and type something in all 25 fields? If the fields are all the same than a simple JavaScript can set them, save that script to one of your sites (or localhost) and inject it with a bookmark (see answer)

Comment: just noticed it doesn't work in Chrome but works in FireFox, for Chrome I guess you have to add userscript, see how pinterest does it: http://about.pinterest.com/goodies/ (pin it buttoon)

Comment: @HMR It's the JavaScript for the bookmark that I need help with

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would not to copy and paste the code every time but to have the code in a javascript file on your server to add this code in a random page you can add a bookmark with the following content:

```
javascript:void(function(doc){ 
 var s= document.createElement('script');
 s.src='myrul';
 document.head.appendChild(s);
})(document);
```

I've added whitespace so it's easier to read but this should be all on one line. The value for **myurl** should be the location of your script.

Your script can then make an XMLHttpRequest to the server that reads the parameters needed for the current page and sets them in the needed text boxes.

To start the script you can just open the bookmark when viewing the page.

[UPDATE]

As for the script to set the values of the inputs you can get all the inputs and set them with values from an array like so:

```
var myInputs=[0,1,2,3,5],//skip inputs[4] because it's a button
var myValues=["hello","how","are","you","today"];
inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("input"),i
for(i=0;i<myInputs.length;i++){
  inputs[myInputs[i]].value=myValues[i];
}
//you can repeat this with textareas or checkboxes
//by re setting inputs: inputs=document.getElementsById("textarea");
//then re set values and if needed myInputs (if you need to skip some textareas)
```

Comment: It's the script that sets the text in the correct fields that I need help with

Comment: @user2392128 Could you give some information about the fields properties and how they can be found using script? You did not answer if the fields need to be the same for all or differrent for specific website.

Comment: All the fields are the same for each site. There are a bunch of WYSIWYG editors on the page and they hold text that will be sent to people when a donation is made or received. We are trying to make the responses consistent for all the sites we manage. So all sites have the same fields and will need to have the same text inserted. I login to the admin for each site and go to each WYSIWYG field and paste text that I copied form a document. Then log out and do the same in another site.

Comment: var myInputs=[0,1,2,3,5];
var myValues=["hello","how","are","you","today"];
inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
[
<textarea id=​"admin_email_body" name=​"admin_email_body" cols=​"75" rows=​"8" style=​"width:​ 100%;​ height:​ 250px;​ display:​ none;​" class=​"wfEditor mce_editable source" wrap=​"off" aria-hidden=​"true">​…​</textarea>​
, 
<textarea id=​"user_email_body" name=​"user_email_body" cols=​"75" rows=​"8" style=​"width:​ 100%;​ height:​ 250px;​ display:​ none;​" class=​"wfEditor mce_editable source" wrap=​"off" aria-hidden=​"true">​…​</textarea>​
,

Comment: I pasted that in the JavaScript console and it didn't fill anything in the fields but it gave me that output in the console

Comment: pseudo code means you have to change it to fit your need. If I don't have the html and the values you wish them to have there is no way I can write code that will work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript Console from Google Chrome.
Go on Chrome and Press the key sequence:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for Windows 
or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for Mac.

Paste (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) your code an press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>